Why is my mutual information negative in Python, and how can I accommodate that?
I'm calculating the mutual information between two 1 qubit subsystems in a quantum state using Python. Theoretically, mutual information should always be non-negative. However, I'm encountering very small negative values (on the order of 10^-8) in my results. I suspect these might be due to numerical precision issues, but I'm not entirely sure how to address them.

Thresholding: I tried setting very small negative values to zero,
but I would prefer a more rigorous solution.
Higher PrecisionCalculations: Using the decimal module for higher precision, but it
didn't completely resolve the issue.

Is this small negative value likely due to numerical precision errors inherent in floating-point arithmetic in Python? How can I modify my calculations to avoid these small negative values rigorously? Is there a better way to handle this within the floating-point limitations? Are there any best practices for handling such precision issues in quantum information calculations?
Additional Info:
I'm using NumPy for numerical calculations.
The density matrices are Hermitian, positive semi definite and normalized.
The small negative values appear sporadically and are typically very close to zero.

Assuming this is indeed a numerical precision problem, I think this depends a lot on your specific calculation and hardware settings. An example calculation of eigvalsh is here: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node89.html - notice how in their example the absolute eigenvalue error is already lower bounded as $\sim 10^{-8}$. Maybe it will help to provide your code.

Are you sure all your NumPy arrays are defined as np.complex128? I.e. for the density matrices, if they have complex entries I would use np.complex128 as data type, otherwise you can always use np.float64 for real entries arrays.

Yes, I defined it as np.complex128.

@forky40 Interesting! So how can I mitigate this. In fact, I used eigvalsh, but when I printed it, the type is float64. For a case where I need mutual information to be zero, I am getting it as 10^-8 too

what code are you using to compute the mutual information? Do you observe this more often when matrices have eigenvalues close to zero? I'm assuming you checked that the matrices you're operating on do have eigenvalues strictly within [0,1] that sum to 1? Including explicit examples where this happen to the post would help a lot
